# FMX Delphi 10.2 webcam Access Violation but only sometimes

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, webcam

Can anyone help me with this? I made an application in Delphi 10.2 with FireMonkey that displays video from a webcam on my Form, and on an action I insert it into a database. Code for webcam is like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EDgCyE0MSVo

I use the `TVideoCaptureDevice` class and this code:

```pascal
VideoCamera := TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultVideoCaptureDevice;
if VideoCamera <> nil then
begin
  VideoCamera.OnSampleBufferReady := SampleBufferReady;
  VideoCamera.StartCapture;
end
else
begin
  // MessageDlg('.',  TMsgDlgType.mtWarning, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0);
end;
```

In the `SampleBufferReady()` procedure, I have this line of code:

```pascal
VideoCamera.SampleBufferToBitmap(frame, true);
```

When I close the application, I have this code:

```pascal
if VideoCamera <> nil then
  VideoCamera.StopCapture;
```

Application works fine for thousands of times, but some times I get an Access Violation, I suppose somewhere in `FMX.Media` or in `System`, as you can see:

[Print screen from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17zLD.png)

or maybe this one

[Next print screen from debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0gBe.png)

How can I figure out what happens?

As you can see below, I can't change the frame rate

[Print screen with frame rate change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgsVu.png)

When I list AvailableCaptureSettings I get only 30 fps

[Available settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAVBI.png)

Now I have compleatly differnet print screen from debugger

[New print screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqCul.png)

As you say, I made a new simple project. This is the complete code:

```
unit Unit3;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants, FMX.Media,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Objects, FMX.Layouts;

type
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
    layCamera1: TLayout;
    imgCamera1: TImage;
    Rectangle1: TRectangle;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    VideoCamera : TVideoCaptureDevice;
    procedure SampleBufferSync;
    procedure SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject; const ATime: TMediaTime);
  end;

var
  Form3: TForm3;
  frame: TBitmap;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm3.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  if VideoCamera <> nil then
    VideoCamera.StopCapture;

end;

procedure TForm3.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  VideoCamera:= TCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultVideoCaptureDevice;
  if VideoCamera <> nil then
  begin
      VideoCamera.OnSampleBufferReady := SampleBufferReady;
      VideoCamera.StartCapture;
  end
  else
  begin

  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.SampleBufferReady(Sender: TObject; const ATime: TMediaTime);
begin
  if frame = nil then
    frame := TBitmap.Create;

  VideoCamera.SampleBufferToBitmap(frame, true);


  imgCamera1.Bitmap.Assign(frame);

end;

procedure TForm3.SampleBufferSync;
begin
  try
     if frame = nil then
      frame := TBitmap.Create;
    VideoCamera.SampleBufferToBitmap(frame, true);
    imgCamera1.Bitmap.Assign(frame);
  except on E:Exception do
  begin
     MessageDlg(E.Message, TMsgDlgType.mtWarning, [TMsgDlgBtn.mbOK], 0);
  end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

When I started the program, it worked for a while, but accidentally crashes after a few minutes (sometimes 2 minutes other times 22 minutes) with this debug window

[image: Debugger window]

Another problem is that sometimes, when I close a program, it doesn't close until I force it by press the stop button in Delphi

Comment: Run your application under the debugger to see where the access violation occurs and edit your question with that information.

Comment: I did it, of course. But I cannot figure where it happens. When I get Access Violetion debugger stops on postition in System unite as you can see in picture above. I putted break points almost every where in my code, I put try except also every where and I dont get exception any time. I cannot figure what happens

Comment: Your screen dump do not show the debugger in action. You should have a look at the call stack (View / Debug window / call stack) and see the first line of your own code. Of course you must build the debug configuration and also check the project option "use debug dcu" to get as much as possible information.

Comment: are you using threads?

Comment: This is what I get. Delphi raises Access Violetion and stops in GETMEM.INC on the line 1973 in function SysGetMem(Size: NativeInt): Pointer; but I dont know how program get there. I cannot put print screen here in comment

Comment: Yes, I have threads in my app

Comment: Have you looked at the call stack as I said? You can edit the question to put the correct screen dump (the one showing the line where the AV occurs and also showing the call stack.

Comment: I edited my question and put print screen but call stack is empty. I maybe do something wrong

Comment: After that I have onother print screen. Maybe that helps

Comment: The last screen dump is much better. You should have enlarged the call stack window so that we see everything. Quartz.dll and qcap.dll are parts of Microsoft DirectShow where the high-level webcam driver is located. I see that the execution is stopped on Synchronize. This makes me think that you use the bitmap to update the GUI and for that you use synchronize. This will block the capture thread during the screen update. Maybe DirectShow doesn't like to be blocked to long.

Comment: I wrote  video capture application long time ago. I remember I had similar issue. I sorted it out by copying the frame buffer in another area of memory and sent a message to the main thread with that area (You can use synchronize to do that but the sync'ed routine must be very fast, just save the date in a queue for processing by the GUI thread. When the frame has been processed, the GUI thread notifies the capture thread. If a frame come from the capture thread before the previous has been processed, it is simply dropped.

Comment: To confirm it is this kind of problem, change the frame rate to a very low rate so that - in your current code - the GUI thread has always enough time to process the frame before the next frame is captured. If it work with low frame rate, then probably what I said is the issue. If it still fails, then there is something else.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answers. I tried to change the frame rate, but I can't. Can you see the new print screen in my question..

Comment: Some camera accept only specific frame rate. For those you cannot assign an arbitrary frame rate. Sometimes, the camera comes with a setting application to change parameter outside of any application.

Comment: When I list AvailableCaptureSettings I get only 30 fps. You can see print screen

Comment: What is the camera model and manufacturer? Maybe this camera can only be set by an external program (setup or control panel applet).

Comment: I tried 2 webcams (Logitech C170 and Canion VCAM 813) and both are equipped only with 30 fps. I have tried some software from the Internet, but there is no possibility of reducing fps.

Comment: Annoying...  I have only one more suggestion: Try to reproduce the issue with the most simple program possible. Maybe the sample in Delphi documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Sydney/en/FMX.CameraComponent_Sample or https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/42558 and see if this suffer from the same problem.

Comment: I'm testing your minimal application. It is running for more than one hour without any problem. I have a Logitech C310 webcam. Windows 10 Pro 20H2 ver 19042.685 with all updates installed. Delphi 10.4.1 update 1, ver  27.0.38860.1461.

Comment: I really appreciate your attempts to help me. I use a logitech C170 web camera. My machine is running on Windows 10 PRO build 19041 and Delphi 10.2 build 25.0.26309.314
I will try in a few days on another machine with different web cam, maybe Delphi 10.4

Comment: Probably the most important thing is to use the very latest Delphi version, currently 10.4.1. Lots of work has been done in FMX and in many other areas of the product. The application runs for more than 2 hours without any issue. Why don't you upgrade you Windows to the latest one? It is free thru Windows Update.  Major releases are not installed if you don't select them.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, I have built the "simple new project" the OP published in his question.

It is running for more than 6 hours without any problem and is still running while I'm doing other things. I have a Logitech C310 webcam. Windows 10 Pro 20H2 ver 19042.685 with all updates installed. Delphi 10.4.1 update 1, ver 27.0.38860.1461.

My conclusion is that there is a bug in Delphi 10.2 that the OP is using. That bug has been fixed at least in Delphi 10.4.1 that I'm using.